# Linq and deferred evaluation

Tags: c#, linq, generic-collections

> *When you use LINQ to define an enumerable collection, either by using the LINQ extension methods or by using query operators,the application
>   does not actually build the collection at the time that the LINQ
>   extension method is executed; the collection is enumerated only when
>   you iterate over it. This means that the data in the original
>   collection can change between executing a LINQ query and retrieving
>   the data that the query identifies; you will always fetch the most
>   up-to-date data.*
>
> **Microsoft Visual C# 2013 step by step written by John Sharp**

I have written the following code:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> res = numbers.FindAll(a => a > 0).Select(b => b).ToList();
numbers.Add(99);
foreach (int item in res)
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
```

The result of the above code is shown bellow:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,

Why is that going like this? I know about `Func`, `Action` and `Predicate` but I can not figure out what is going on here. Based on the above definition the code is not rational.

Comment: Try removing the `ToList()` at the end

Comment: @MatiasCicero I tried it but did not have any effect.

Comment: `ToList()` creates *new* list (`res`) and copy all the items, but you add into *old* one (`numbers`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I removed the ToList() and it had the same result (99 was excluded).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the `ToList()` at the end, which is creating a new collection, you have another issue.

The problem is that you are not using LINQ at all.

`FindAll` is not a LINQ extension method.

You should use `Where`:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> res = numbers.Where(a => a > 0);

numbers.Add(99);

foreach (int item in res)
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
```

Comment: This is the actual culprit, and the only complete answer.  I completely skimmed over the `FindAll`.

Answer (score 2):

First you set an int type list that contains 1,2,3,4,5 .
then you used linq to create and define an enumeration collection .
here describes how the linq work :
first find all numbers that they are bigger than zero, as you see all of the items in the above list are bigger than zero , then select all of them and put them in a list . when you add 99 to the number list it doesn't effect on the enumeration collection that defined because it'll create a new collection and pass the items in it and it hasn't any references to the numbers list .
you can delete .ToList() at the end of the linq expression, it'll result in :
1,2,3,4,5,99 .

Good Luck

Comment: actually I guess you have not cared about deffered evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

`ToList` creates a *new* instance of `List<T>` and copy all the items into it:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e276d6892241255b

```
 public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
   if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
     return new List<TSource>(source);
 }
```

So if you want to have `99` in the `res` you should add it into `res`, not into `numbers`:

```
 ... 
 var res = numbers
   .Where(a => a > 0) // Filter out; Select is redundant
   .ToList();

 res.Add(99);

 Console.Write(string.Join(", ", res));
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ToList()` is not actually the only problem. FindAll returns a new List. So when you call

```
IEnumerable<int> res = numbers.FindAll(a => a > 0)
```

That is the same as doing

```
IEnumerable<int> newList = new List<int>();
foreach (int old in numbers) {
   if (old > 0) newList.Add(old);
}
```

So when you add a new item to numbers, it is no longer relevant. You are searching against the list returned by FindAll rather than the original list.

Answer (score 1):

You will see the result you expect if you defer (or remove all together) the `ToList()` operation until your foreach loop.  `ToList` will execute the Linq expression the same as enumerating.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> res = numbers.FindAll(a => a > 0).Select(b => b);

numbers.Add(99);

foreach (int item in res)
    Console.Write(item + ", ");

// another option, but not necessary in most cases...
foreach (int item in res.ToList())
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
```

Comment: Still prints out `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, `

Comment: @GlennFerrie as I have mentioned in the comments, removing ToList() does not make the appropriate answer which should be included 99. I have tried it in Visual Studio 2013 and did not work.