# Shouldn't sum method be deferred in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<int> no = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var res2 = no.Sum(a => a * a);
Console.WriteLine(res2);
no.Add(100);
Console.WriteLine(res2);
```

I expect the following result:

> 55
>   10055

but both are 55

> 55
>   55

I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004141/linq-and-deferred-evaluation) which is about deferred evaluation but was not helpful. `Sum` is an extension method, but the result is not what I have mentioned. Why?

Comment: What is it you expect as an result?

Comment: So what do you expect and what result do you get?

Comment: `Sum` is not deferred.  Only the methods that return an `IEnumerable` are deferred.

Comment: What is the question? what are you expecting to get and what are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only functions that return an `IEnumerable<T>` can be deferred in Linq (since they can be wrapped in an object that allows deferring).

The result of `Sum` is an `int`, so it can't possibly defer it in any meaningful way:

```
var res2 = no.Sum(a => a * a);
// res2 is now an integer with a value of 55
Console.WriteLine(res2);
no.Add(100);

// how are you expecting an integer to change its value here?
Console.WriteLine(res2);
```

You can defer the execution (not really defer, but explicitly call it), by assigning the lambda to, for example, a `Func<T>`:

```
List<int> no = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Func<int> res2 = () => no.Sum(a => a * a);
Console.WriteLine(res2());
no.Add(100);
Console.WriteLine(res2());
```

This should correctly give `55` and `10055`

Answer (score 1):

Generally you may assume that as long as a Linq function returns a IEnumerable or IQueryable of something, then the execution is probably deferred.

When the returned value is one item of type TSource or an object that implements ICollection < TSource > you can be assured that the execution is not deferred (anyone knows for any exceptions?)

To be absolutely certain: the MSDN descriptions of the Enumerable functions describe whether the function is implemented by using deferred execution.

For example [Enumerable.Select:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated...

The function [Enumerable.Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb347632(v=vs.110).aspx) is not implemented using deferred execution. So if the sequence changes after you calculated the Max, the result of Max is not changed.

See also [Stackoverflow: when is a Linq function deferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894490/linq-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-find-out-deferred-execution-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

A few LINQ methods (like `Where` and `Select`) are deferred because computing one result is independent from computing the next result. But not all methods that operate on an `IEnumerable<T>` are necessarily deferred.

For example, `Sum` will reduce all elements of the sequence into one. As such, it can compute nothing at all or everything, but there's no way to do anything in-between. Its authors chose to break their usual LINQ habit and they made it compute eagerly rather than lazily.

This is proven by the fact that `Sum` on an `IEnumerable<int>` has a return type of `int`, which is an already calculated integer:

```
int res2 = no.Sum(a => a * a);
```

If you want to defer the calculation of `Sum`, there's a simple way -- use a `Func<int>`:

```
Func<int> res2 = () => no.Sum(a => a * a);
```

Alternatively, you can make it a LINQ-like extension method:

```
public static Func<int> LazySum(this IEnumerable<int> sequence, Func<int, int> selector)
        => () => sequence.Sum(selector);
```

And then use it like this:

```
var res2 = no.LazySum(a => a * a);
```

Regardless of which one you choose, you can verify that it will give you deferred computation:

```
Console.WriteLine(res2()); // prints 55
no.Add(100);
Console.WriteLine(res2()); // prints 10055
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions that return an IEnumerable can be deferred in Linq because they can be wrapped in an object that allows deferring.