# When is data loaded into app server's memory?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, binary

We have a DB table having a binary column. Each row stores the file content of a file. We want to avoid loading the file content (each can be 10-20Mb in size) into app server's memory unless when necessary.

In the following queries, will the file content be loaded into app server's memory? If yes, during which function call?

```
// Query 1
dataContext.DataFiles.OrderBy(w => w.atimestamp).ToList();


// Query 2
var filesizes = from DataFiles in dataContext.DataFiles
                select DataFiles.FileContent.Length;
```

Comment: Q1 -> load into memory as you are doing .ToList()
Q2 -> will not, as that would be IQueryable<int>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq methods which return `IEnumerable<TSource>` or `IQueriable<TSource>` are implemented to be deferred executed.
Being differed executed, only when you call `ToList()`/`ToArray()` (or one of the linq extension methods that do not return a collection like `Sum()`/`Max()`/`FirstOrDefault()` etc.) will actually be executed and will retrieve the data

In your first query, the `OrderBy()` is not yet executed until you try to retrieve specific items or call the `ToList()`. However, even though this is deferred executed, this one will have to consume the entire collection the moment you requested the first item (whereas `Select()` for example will continue to be deferred for the entire collection - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894490/linq-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-find-out-deferred-execution-or-not) for some more details)

In your second query, after that line, nothing will yet to be executed.

You can read this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/) about linq and deferred execution and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39017509/6400526) from yesterday that also askes about the matter of when linq and deferred